# Show whitespace only on selected text in IntelliJ IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, whitespace

Like how it is in Sublime Text. Currently I've only found the ability to show whitespace permanently.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since version 2023.1 there is an option to enable this in the settings under `Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance`.

[image: Screen shot of the Show Whitespaces setting]

For older version an interesting trick to get the desired effect has been posted in [the feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94918).

1. Enable `Show whitespaces` in `File | Settings | Editor | General | Appearance`
2. Set the `Text | Whitespaces` foreground color to be the same as the editor background color in `File | Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`

Result: Whitespace is invisible by default, but when the text is selected the background color will change and the whitespace becomes visible.

Answer (score 3):

In IDEA 2023.1, there is an option in `Settings | Editor | General | Appearance | Show whitespaces | Selection` for it.